# Execute mysql query over multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables:

1. users: contains the registered users.
2. courses: contains available courses.
3. userscourses: has two columns: user_id and course_id. Whenever a user joins  a course, a new record is created that relate that course with the user.

I want to create a mysql query that; given a user_id, is going to fetch all courses joined by the user. Also, with each course row, I want to add a column that represents how many users are in that course.

I made a query but it does not give me the desired result:

```
SELECT courses.id AS CourseID, courses.name AS Name, COUNT(usersCourses.userId) AS JoinedUsersNumber 
FROM courses, users, usersCourses 
WHERE users.id = courses.userId 
AND usersCourses.courseId = courses.id 
AND usersCourses.courseId=courses.id 
AND usersCourses.userId='31'
```

Can anybody tell me how to achieve this or tell me what's wrong with my query?

**EDIT**
This is an example:

users table

```
   id       |     username
--------------------------
   u1       |      user01
   u2       |      user02
   u3       |      user03
   u4       |      user04
```

courses table:

```
   id       |     name
--------------------------
   c1       |    course01
   c2       |    course02
   c3       |    course03
   c4       |    course04
```

userscourses table:

```
 userId     |    courseId
--------------------------
   u1       |      c1
   u1       |      c2
   u1       |      c3
   u2       |      c1
   u3       |      c1
   u4       |      c1
   u2       |      c2
   u3       |      c2
```

Expected Result (user_id=u1):

```
  name      |  Joined Users
--------------------------
 course01   |       4
 course02   |       3
 course03   |       1
```

Comment: You forgot GROUP BY!

Comment: @jarlh When I put the GROUP BY it does give me all courses by the user but doesn't give me the number of users in each course.

Comment: Provide some sample data and expected result from that sample data.

Comment: Also, you join is wrong in style and probably in content as well. Use proper INNER JOIN and don't join the users table

Comment: Example Added @AbhikChakraborty

Comment: your query does not match with the table columns.

Comment: I corrected it @10sw33

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Joining back on the userscourses table to get all the users on that course:-

```
SELECT courses.id AS CourseID, courses.name AS Name, COUNT(usersCourses2.userId) AS JoinedUsersNumber 
FROM users
INNER JOIN usersCourses 
ON users.id = usersCourses.userId 
INNER JOIN courses
ON usersCourses.courseId = courses.id 
INNER JOIN usersCourses usersCourses2
ON usersCourses.courseId = usersCourses2.courseId
WHERE usersCourses.userId='31'
GROUP BY courses.id AS CourseID, courses.name AS Name
```

or if you want the count of users on that course to exclude the selected users (ie, you want a count of other users):-

```
SELECT courses.id AS CourseID, courses.name AS Name, COUNT(usersCourses2.userId) AS JoinedUsersNumber 
FROM users
INNER JOIN usersCourses 
ON users.id = usersCourses.userId 
INNER JOIN courses
ON usersCourses.courseId = courses.id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN usersCourses usersCourses2
ON usersCourses.courseId = usersCourses2.courseId
AND users.id != usersCourses2.userId 
WHERE usersCourses.userId='31'
GROUP BY courses.id AS CourseID, courses.name AS Name
```

Answer (score 0):

First make a query that returns the course user counts:

```
 SELECT course.id, course.name, count(*) as JoinedUsersNumber 
 FROM course 
 JOIN usersCourses
 ON course.id=usersCourses.courseId
 GROUP BY course.id, course.name
```

then use this as a sub-query, so something like

```
SELECT 
  c.id AS CourseID, 
  c.name AS Name, 
  c.JoinedUsersNumber 
FROM 
     SELECT course.id, course.name, count(*) as JoinedUsersNumber 
     FROM course 
     JOIN usersCourses
     ON course.id=usersCourses.courseId
     GROUP BY course.id, course.name
) c
JOIN 
  usersCourses ON c.id = usersCourses.courseId = 
JOIN
  users ON users.id = usersCourses.userId   
WHERE usersCourses.userId=31
```

Answer (score 0):

your query is

```
SELECT courses.id AS CourseID, courses.name AS Name, COUNT(usersCourses.userId) AS JoinedUsersNumber 
FROM courses, users, usersCourses 
WHERE users.id = courses.userId 
AND usersCourses.courseId = courses.id 
AND usersCourses.courseId=courses.id 
AND usersCourses.userId='31'
```

according to your schema

- you have joined `users.id = courses.userId`  but you donot have userId in your courses table
- you have not created joined condition of user with its bridge table. you have joined same column twice

> AND usersCourses.courseId = courses.id 
>     AND usersCourses.courseId=courses.id

hope this will help you.

```
 SELECT courses.id AS CourseID, courses.name AS Name, COUNT(usersCourses.userId) AS JoinedUsersNumber 
        FROM courses, users, usersCourses 
        WHERE 
        usersCourses.courseId = courses.id 
        AND usersCourses.userId=users.userId 
        AND usersCourses.userId='31'
        Group By courses.name
```

Comment: This only gave me the courses but the number of joined users is only 1 for all courses.

Comment: your query does not match with the table columns. thats why may be you are missing something to convert it to your original query.

Answer (score 0):

Your join is in a deprecated style and probably wrong in content as well. Also, you need to add a Group by on courses id and name. Try this:

```
SELECT courses.id AS CourseID, courses.name AS Name, COUNT(usersCourses.userId) AS JoinedUsersNumber 
FROM courses 
INNER JOIN usersCourses ON usersCourses.courseId=courses.id 
WHERE usersCourses.userId='31'
GROUP BY courses.id, courses.name
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6a134/4/0

```
SELECT *
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      userscourses.user_id   AS user_id,
      users.user_name        AS user_name,
      userscourses.course_id AS course_id,
      courses.course_name    AS course_name
    FROM
      users, courses, userscourses
    WHERE
      users.user_id = userscourses.user_id
      AND courses.course_id = userscourses.user_id
      AND userscourses.user_id = 1
  ) userTable
  LEFT JOIN
  (
    SELECT
      course_id,
      COUNT(user_id) AS sum_participant
    FROM
      userscourses
    GROUP BY
      course_id
  ) courseTable
    ON userTable.course_id = courseTable.course_id
```

Answer (score 0):

This would work :

```
SELECT C.name,
   COUNT(U.username) As JoinedUser
FROM usercourse UC INNER JOIN users U ON UC.userId = U.id
INNER JOIN courses C ON C.id = UC.courseId
WHERE U.userId = '31'
GROUP BY C.name
```